# NullPointerException at sendBroadcast() from Service to Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a `Service` class and an main `Acitivity` class which is supposed to receive broadcasts from the Service class with method sendBroadcast.

It crashes when running the method `sendBroadcast` from my `Service` class.

here is part of my Service class (**EDITED**):

```
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;

    public static final String BT_CONNECTING = "com.android.mypackage.action.BTService.BT_CONNECTING";

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder() {
            BTService getService() {
                    return BTService.this;
            }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return mBinder;
    }

    public synchronized void setState(int state) {
            mState = state;
            if ( state == STATE_CONNECTING ) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(BT_CONNECTING);
                    try {
                            sendBroadcast(myIntent);
                    }
                    catch (NullPointerException e) {}
            }
    }
```

And here is part of my Activity class which is supposed to receive the broadcasted intents (**EDITED**):

```
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    if(intent.getAction().equals(BTService.BT_CONNECTING))
                            mState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                    }
            };

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                    LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
                    myService = binder.getService();
                    mBound = true;
            }

            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
                    mBound = false;
            }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, BTService.class);
            myService.bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BTService.BTConnecting);
            registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
```

I get NullPointerException when calling sendBroadcast(intent) method. Any tips on solving this is greatly appreciated.

here is the log:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mypackage/com.android.mypackage.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:271)
    at com.android.mypackage.BTService.setState(BTService.java:68)
    at com.android.mypackage.BTService.connect(BTService.java:90)
    at com.android.mypackage.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:78)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace from LogCat.

Comment: Ok. I've edited main post now with stack trace from LogCat.

Comment: it doesn't make any sense that you are seeing a NPE in the logcat while you are catching this very exception. are you sure this is the code executed ?

Comment: this is caught without the try catch statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your stack trace, it appears you are somehow directly referencing your `BTService` service. Since you cut your `onCreate()` short I can't be certain how you are doing it, but I will take a guess.

Did you instantiate this service directly inside of your activity (use `new BTService()`)? If so, then the reason you are getting this error is because your Service has no context bound to it. You must let Android create your service for you by calling `startService()` or `bindService()`.

Comment: That helped! It reduced amount of errors in stack trace to:          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.android.mypackage.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:78)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)

Comment: Whats at line 78 in MyActivity.java? Whatever it is, its causing the NullPointerException.

Comment: that is this line: myService.bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); ... I've edited in some more code in the main post so it might be easier to see.

Comment: Don't use myService.bindService(). myService is null. Just call bindService() since your are already a Context object. Also, remember that myService won't be set until some unknown time, so be sure you don't call anything on it until mBound is true.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your `sendBroadcast` call to: `context.sendBroadcast(intent);`

Comment: Ok. That doesn't work; Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method sendBroadcast(Intent) from the type Context.

Comment: try: `Context.sendBroadcast(new Intent (context, name.class));`

Comment: This worked for me using  `MyContext = getApplicationContext();` and then `MyContext.sendBroadcast(intent);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`